# Excel VBA: vLookup on a specific column in a Named Table and replacing value if it matches with multiple criteria and wildcard

Tags: excel, vba, match

I'd like to create a macro that will take the name of the resource and do a vLookup (or similar action) on another table to find the matching resource manager's info, then replace the NULL manager name and email address in the first table with the manager info that corresponds to that Resource. The end goal is to complete my table with the Generic Resource's manager and their email address.

I have a table on Sheet1 named "Resources":

["Resources" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ycAkx.png)

I also have a table on Sheet2 named "ManagerLookup":

["ManagerLookup" table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mHYcT.jpg)

How can I loop through each Resource Name in my table to match the resources up with their correct manager? I'm only looking to replace the manager fields for which I have a match on the Resource Name. I can't only perform vlookup on rows with a "NULL" Manager name, since my data does not only use "NULL" for missing manager names (sometimes it's different).

I've searched for hours and can't find anything, but I need a clean way to do this. Also worth noting is that the "Resources" table doesn't ever get larger than about 500 rows so processing time is not a factor here. I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: Always best to include whatever code you've already tried, along with a description of what problem(s) you ran into.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the first 2 letters are unique to a manager like on your example, remove the # sign from the Managers table and on the resources table use the formula:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(LEFT(A2,2)&"*",Sheet2!A:B,2,FALSE),"Not found")
```